# Why can't I clone "FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection"?

Tags: git, ssh, putty, atlassian-sourcetree

When trying to clone a repository, I get an error, what am I doing wrong?
I use putty, ssh access.
I clone a repository from Bitbucket via Sourcetree.

```sh
FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection  
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: early EOF  
fatal: index-pack failed  
Completed with errors, see above.
```

If you set Clone depth 1 in the cloning settings (the standard depth is 0) then cloning is performed without errors, but then cloning is superficial and so this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете вы напишите вопрос на английском языке? (Please may you write the question in English?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: yes, sorry, I confused something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Sourcetree-3-2-6-FATAL-ERROR-Server-unexpectedly-closed-network/qaq-p/1229379) where, indeed in Sourcetree, changing the clone depth to 1 (under `Advanced Options` > `Clone depth`) could help.

See also "[Fix SourceTree: Git over SSH](https://crypted2.com/2018/01/06/fix-sourcetree-git-over-ssh/)"

> In order to connect to the git repo over SSH, I advise to install the complete PuTTY package from the official WebSite.
>
> After this, you can copy the latest executables from the PuTTY folder (Depending on the version, usually: `C:\Program Files\PuTTY`) to the SourceTree folder (Depending on the version, usually: `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\SourceTree\app-2.0.20.1\tools\putty`)
>
> - plink.exe
> - (pageant.exe)
> - (puttygen.exe)
> - (putty.exe)
>
> Now you can configure normally the connection in SourceTree and with this latest version of plink it will work.

Test also the same clone in command-line, outside of SourceTree, and check if the HTTPS URL would work any better.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem! You helped a lot!
I used https://crypted2.com/2018/01/06/fix-sourcetree-git-over-ssh/

Comment: @MaxDuma Great! Well done. (Фантастический! Отличная работа.)